# Kindly advice DataWeave logic to auto increment numbers with a given format

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Existing logic:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun counter(a)= (a/10 splitBy ".")[0]

fun append (b)= if (b=="0")"00000000000"
else if (b=="1") "0000000000" else if (b=="2")"0000000000" else false

---
payload map{
  id:append((counter($$)))++ $$
}
```

sample payload :

```
[
    {
        "message": "1"
    }
    {
        "message": "2"
    }
    {
        "message": "3"
    }
    {
        "message": "4"
    }
    {
        "message": "5"
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
    [
      {
        "id": "000000000000"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000001"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000002"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000003"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000004"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000005"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000006"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000007"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000008"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000009"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000010"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000011"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000012"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000013"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000014"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000015"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000016"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000017"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000018"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000019"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000020"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000021"
      }
    ]
```

I can't manually type `else if (b=="2") "0000000000"` up to 12 digits/positions of zeros in the existing DataWeave logic. Please provide a nested for loop approach which I can implement in the function to append and handle this level of increment or any approach which can solve this and not return false

Comment: For next time please read the help on how to use correctly formatting in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. This question was hard to read as it was.

Comment: A function returning strings or false (ie different types) is probably not a good idea for long term maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(1 to 100) map ((number) -> {
    "id": number as String {format: "000000000000"}
})
```

Replace the 100 with the number of elements you want